# Pgfplot: create own marker or fill marker with pattern (legend)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a hatched area and would like to create a marker with same hatched filling for the legend. But it seems like even setting just a marker doesn't work -- what's going wrong? And it would be greatif some could explain me how to fill the marker with a hatching/pattern.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=1.12
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      legend style={cells={align=left}}
   ]  
    \addplot {rnd};
\addlegendentry{a};

\addplot [ draw=none, postaction={pattern = north east lines, pattern color=red}] coordinates {
    (0, 1)
    (0, 0)
    (2, 0)
    (2, 1)
};

\addlegendimage{red, mark=square}%pattern = north east lines, pattern color=red
\addlegendentry{b};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\addplot` command defines already a legend image that is used for the second legend entry (`b`). Add `area legend` to the options of this plot to get a square filled with the pattern instead the default `line legend` image.

Note that there will be a black border because the original `area legend` style uses a `\draw` command. To remove this border you can add `legend image post style={draw opacity=0}` to the plot options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      legend style={cells={align=left}}
   ]  
    \addplot {rnd};
\addlegendentry{a};

\addplot [draw=none,pattern = north east lines, pattern color=red,
    area legend,
    legend image post style={draw opacity=0}% if the border of the legend image should be removed
] coordinates {
    (0, 1)
    (0, 0)
    (2, 0)
    (2, 1)
};
\addlegendentry{b};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you define a new style for the legend image using `\path` instead `\draw`.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12,
    my area legend/.style={
        legend image code/.code={%
            \path[#1](0cm,-.1cm)rectangle(.6cm,.1cm);% \path instead \draw
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      legend style={cells={align=left}},
   ]  
    \addplot {rnd};
\addlegendentry{a};

\addplot[draw=none,pattern = north east lines, pattern color=red,
    my area legend
    ] coordinates {
    (0, 1)
    (0, 0)
    (2, 0)
    (2, 1)
};
\addlegendentry{b};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `legend image post style={draw opacity=0}` effects the opacity of the whole plot mark, ie the plot mark vanishes (incl. the pattern). Instead I used `legend image post style={draw=white}` to change the color of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own marker with `\pgfdeclareplotmark`, here an attempt to make one that can achieve what you want

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{mymark}
{%
\path[fill=white,postaction={pattern = north east lines, pattern color=red}] (-\pgfplotmarksize,-\pgfplotmarksize) rectangle (\pgfplotmarksize,\pgfplotmarksize);
}
```

In the above code best if we define `pattern color` as same of line color ( I can't find how to do this )

**Code**

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=1.12
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mymark}
{%
\path[fill=white,postaction={pattern = north east lines, pattern color=red}] (-\pgfplotmarksize,-\pgfplotmarksize) rectangle (\pgfplotmarksize,\pgfplotmarksize);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      legend style={cells={align=left}}
   ]  
    \addplot {rnd};
\addlegendentry{a}
\addlegendimage{mark=mymark,red}
\addlegendentry{b}
    \addplot [ draw=none, postaction={pattern = north east lines, pattern color=red}] coordinates {
    (0, 1)
    (0, 0)
    (2, 0)
    (2, 1)
};

%pattern = north east lines, pattern color=red


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```